# Implementing redux-toolkit error with async function types and usage

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to implement react redux toolkit into my application. Everything went fine, but I will need a async function. I was following the basic docs to implement it but I don't know the cause of this issue.
The first issue is regarding to typescript, this file is the `Stock.store.ts`:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AppDispatch, AppThunk } from '.';

const stock = createSlice({
  name: 'stock',
  initialState: {
    counter: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment(state) {
      state.counter += 1;
    },
    decrement(state) {
      state.counter -= 1;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement } = stock.actions;
export default stock.reducer;

function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

export function asyncIncrement(): AppThunk {
// Error here
  return async function (dispatch: AppDispatch) {
    await sleep(3000);
    dispatch(increment());
  };
}
```

Error image:
[image]
This is the main redux file:

```
import { Action, configureStore, ThunkAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import stockReducer from './Stock.store';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    stock: stockReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<string>>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export default store;
```

The second one is trying to implement the call into a component:
[image]

This is a piece of the `App.tsx`:

```
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/redux';

export default function App() {


  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {!isAuthenticated ? (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <AuthRoutes></AuthRoutes>
        </NavigationContainer>
      ) : (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Main />
        </Provider>
      )}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the thunk, where you have `(dispatch: AppDispatch)`, remove the `: AppDispatch` part.  That's already implied by the `AppThunk` usage right before it.